# Tomcat not using context path specified in Spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat8

We are using spring boot for our web application. The context root is defined in WEB-INF/classes/common.properties as follows.

server.contextPath=<>

However after deployment the above value is not read and Tomcat is registering the name of the war as the context root.

Spring boot version = 1.5.2
Tomcat version = 8.0.53

Comment: All the `server.*` settings are for use with an embedded container, they are NOT used when deploying to a servlet container.

Comment: @Pijotrek its for version 2.0 onwards.

Comment: @SourajitBasak oh you are rightm thanks & sorry!

Comment: @M.Deinum in our production environment (Amazon beanstalk) it seems to read the context path properly.

Comment: That is only the case if you run the war with the embedded container, else it will be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

As I know, `server.contextPath =` not work for `war` file, it only work you deploy your application with `jar` file and `Tomcat embedded`.

If you want deploy your application with `Tomcat` and `War` file. You should add `finalName` setting to `pom.xml`. Example:

```
<build>
    ...
    <finalName>context path</finalName>
</build>
```